# how to remove a few characters from a sentece

Tags: javascript, html

this is what i mean:

{input_value: hello,world}

func delete (target, wordstodelete): // delete wordstodelete from target

{new_input_value = delete ",world" from input_value}

so this is my file code:

```
<input id=“extension” type="file”>
<script>
Let e = document.getelementbyid(“extension”).value;
if(e.includes(“.atkp”)) {

}else{
alert(“this file can’t be accessed since it doesn’t have the extention ‘.atpk’.”)
}
</script>
```

i asked google and many other websites like w3schools. i found nothing useful except the `substr()` but it uses numbers. i want a function something like this: `let e-edited = e.substr(".atkr")`, instead does this `let e-edited = e.substr(1, 3)`.
i have nothing to start with. if i have to use the `substr()` method, then i have to make sure that the length is 10 or 8 characters and a name like: `gghh.atkp` or `exampl.atkp`.

Comment: dont worry about the ".atkp" extention because i was trying to make a atkp file launcher

Comment: what is the input and what exatly is the result that you are seeking? It is not so clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many spelling errors in your code! Also, you should not check the value of the form before anyone has submitted the file. You can use an eventListener for that.

HTML

```
<label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
<input type="file" id="extension" name="myfile"><br><br>
```

JS

```
let el = document.getElementById("extension");

el.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  if(e.target.value.includes(".atpk")){
    console.log("this is an atpk")
  } else {
    console.log("this is not an atpk")
  }
})
```

Comment: atkp not atpk. i tried it out, i changes console to alert so i can get the value but it didnt work. i changed atpk to atkp and it worked. next time remenber. it's atkp. it worked but you mistaked

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you try to achieve,

If you want to delete all the occurrences of `wordstodelete` you can use `string.replaceAll`

If you want replace a single occurrence of the `wordstodelete`, then ou can use `string.slice` together with `string.length` or `string.indexOf`

Look at the examples below:

```js
const input = 'filename.extension.filename.extension';
const toDelete = '.extension';


function deleteAllWords(target, wordstodelete) {
  return target.replaceAll(wordstodelete, '');
}
function deletFomTheEnd(target, wordstodelete) {
  return target.slice(0, -wordstodelete.length);
}
function deleteFromWord(target, wordstodelete) {
  const wordsIndex = target.indexOf(wordstodelete);
  return target.slice(0, wordsIndex);
}

console.log('deletFomTheEnd: ', deletFomTheEnd(input, toDelete));
console.log('deleteAllWords: ', deleteAllWords(input, toDelete));
console.log('deleteFromWord: ', deleteFromWord(input, toDelete));
```